# Writing time dependant php scripts for server

Tags: php

Is there a way with PHP to execute PHP functions based on time of day or day of week? I.e. store information to a database every wednesday? That is, without anyone viewing a web page or click a link to check if it wednesday each time? Any help would be great on this. I need a way to read information from a db and write it to a file every so often, i.e. once a week on my server. How can I accomplish these time dependent tasks?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for crontab (for Linux) or Scheduled Tasks (for Windows). You can execute any PHP file directly from the server by running the PHP executable on it.

(Windows) Example:

```
php.exe -f P:\ath\to\php\file.php
```

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet is to set your PHP script to run in Cron.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron

Comment: Worth noting, Windows doesn't have Cron.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha The question said nothing about Windows.

Comment: Nope, but it sure said nothing about Linux either, so it's best to provide the widest reasonable arc of solutions :)